# un while dentro de un html table

Tags: php, javascript, while

Buenos días compañeros (aqui apenas son las 10 am), para ver si me pueden ayudar, porque no se porque no funciona el codigo y explico el codigo en una tabla tengo "X" nombre digamos marcas cuando le doy click en la marca, me debe mostrar todos los productos que tengo de esa marca a la par voy a poner ambos codigos que uso.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"style="overflow:auto;width:100%;font-size:80%; border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom:10px;box-shadow:5px 5px 5px grey;border: 1px solid blue;margin-top:10px">
        <thead><tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;">Proyectos</td></tr></thead>
        <?php while($sub=$db1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){;?>
            <tbody><tr><td  style="overflow:auto;underline;cursor: pointer;color:blue;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;"onclick="proy1(<?php echo $sub['id_empresa'];?>)"><?php echo $sub['proyecto'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><button <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="modal"data-toggle="tooltip"title="Eliminar" onclick="eliminar(<?php echo $sub['id'];?>);"></button></td></tr><?php };?>
        </tbody>
        <!--<tfoot><tr><td>pie de pagina</td></tr></tfoot>--->
    </table>
```

y con el script que uso

```
function proy1(p){
    var id=<?=$id;?>;
    var p=p;
    cadena="ids="+p+"&id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "mod_admin/tpl/config2.php",
        data:cadena,
        success: function(r){
        alert(r);
        $("#sub_proyecto").show();
        }
    })  
};
```

esta parte me funciona de maravillas y sin problemas porque ya he usado el codigo antes en otras cosas ahora bien el codigo para que me muestre el resultado es el siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST['ids'])){
    $ids=$_POST['ids'];}else{$ids=0;
};
$sql3="Select * from ".su." where id=".$ids;
$db2=$dbh->prepare($sql3);
$db2->execute();


<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"style="overflow:auto;width:100%;font-size:80%; border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom:10px;box-shadow:5px 5px 5px grey;border: 1px solid blue;margin-top:10px">
        <thead><tr><td colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;">Sub Proyectos</td></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php while($sub2=$db1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                <td>
                <?php echo $sub2['proyecto'];?>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">
                <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
                        data-toggle="modal"data-toggle="tooltip"title="Eliminar" 
                        onclick="eliminar1(<?=$sub2['id_proyecto'];?>);">
                        </button>
                    </td>
                <?php };?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

ya hice un print_r al resultado del while y con el alert me muestra las array perfecto, ahora bien porque no funciona si en teoría son los mismos códigos, a ver si me pueden ayudar.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, si tu código se ve exactamente así entonces el problema puede ser que en la parte inicial declaras la variable `$db2` y luego dentro del `while`escribiste `$db1`.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? Explica de forma más clara tu problema

Comment: the breaker, tenías razón y ya corregí el código, y sigue sin funcionar. Para explicar que no funciona, es que no me muestra los datos en la tabla pero si dentro agrego un print_r entonces si me muestra los datos que estoy consultando

Comment: No se si resuelva tu problema pero veo que tu tabla solo tiene 2 columnas, por tanto las etiquetas `<tr></tr>` deberían ir dentro del `while`, de otro modo solo tendrás una fila con n columnas.

Comment: no de hecho no me lo resulve la tabla sale en blanco solo el thead sale

Comment: ¿ya probaste hacerle `print_r()` al `$db2`? creo que antes se lo hiciste al `$db1` y como este ya había sido recorrido el puntero ya estaba en el final y ya no tenia mas que mostrar en el `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok gracias a todos por las ayudas ya pude solucionar el problema.
 con el siguiente codigo

```
    function proy1(p){
    var id=<?=$id;?>;
    var p=p;
    cadena="ids="+p+"&id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "mod_admin/tpl/config2.php",
        data:cadena,
        success: function(r){
        $("#sub_proyecto").load("mod_admin/tpl/config2.php",{"ids":p,"id":id});
        $("#sub_proyecto").show();
        }
    })  
}
$("#sub_proyecto").load("mod_admin/tpl/config2.php",{"ids":p,"id":id});-> este codigo era que me hacia falta para poder mostrar en la tabla la consulta si de casualidad otra persona conoce otra solucion entonces que me pase para probar gracias
```